# Position fixed issue in css

Tags: html, css

This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5e37gjtp/. What i want is to my class `content` will begin right after the `header`. I don't want to use margin-top, or padding-top.
This is my code:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

and the css:

```
.header {height:200px;border:1px solid black; width:100%;position:fixed;left:0px;top:0px;}
.content{height:800px;border:1px solid black}
```

As you can see the content is behind the header. I want to show right after it . I want to keep the position fixed because is the header of the page and i want to keep it after scrolling down. Is it possible ? thx

Comment: What's your problem in using `margin-top` or `padding-top`? Because that solves the issue.

Comment: on responsive I need to add or remove from the margin-top or padding-top. For desktop version there will be margin-top:10px; for tablet margin-top:20px and so on . and it is ugly code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It becomes crap and ugly to the core if you are using `absolute` or `top`. Your wish. Better you could use `padding-top` for the `body` that matches the height of the `<header>`:

```css
body {
    margin-top: 210px;
}
.header {
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.content {
    height:800px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/og3auchm/1/**

Comment: "`I don't want to use margin-top, or padding-top.`"

Comment: @CagatayUlubay There's no other way.

Comment: @CagatayUlubay See the above answer.

Comment: I know, fully understand and agree, but I think the OP knows this and wants an alternative.

Comment: I don't want to use margin, padding for my classes, not for the body. srry if I not explain myself 100% correctly. the body did the trick, thx

Comment: @CagatayUlubay See the above comment of OP. `:)`

Comment: Cheat.exe | Well, okey :)

Comment: I thought he wants only an alternative way, but if he is okey with this then this should be the "correct answer" ^^

Answer (score 0):

If the height of your header is always the same, you can simply do:

```
.content{
   height:800px;
   border:1px solid black
   position: absolute;
   top: 200px;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ckmbemzp/

An alternative if your header doesn't have the same height, would be to use a `onLoad` event and calculate the height of your header, which after you can change the `top` property.

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish that by adding  `position:absolute;` and `top:201px;` to your Content, the 1px extra is to because of the 1px border that is calculated in the header.

You might also want to add `left:-1px;` to make align it to the left. I hope this helps!